# Controlling the name of input fields using HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building a form in ASP.NET MVC3 + Razor that posts to a PHP page which uses a different convention for naming the input fields. I need to make MVC's field names conform to the names that the PHP page is using. Instead of the input name being `Customer.EmailAddress`, I need the field name to be `customer[email_address]`.

I've been using the `Html.TextBoxFor`, `Html.LabelFor` and `Html.ValidationMessageFor` methods on other pages, and I'd like to get the same functionality of generating validation from the attributes on my viewmodel. **How do I customize the input name that Html.TextBoxFor is generating, and still get the validation behavior?**

I've seen the Bind attribute, but that only seems to affect data being received by the server, not being rendered by the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was easier than I thought. For anyone trying to solve this problem, here's what I did

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegistrationDetails.Email, null, "customer[email_address]")
```